# Python subprocess: how to pipe to gnuplot a command to plot a variable?

Tags: python, escaping, subprocess, string-formatting, gnuplot

I am not trying to do anything fancy here. I am trying to automate plotting some experiment data in the following script:

```
print "processing: ", filename

gnuplot = Popen(gnuplot_bin,stdin = PIPE).stdin

if state_plot:

        gnuplot.write( "set term x11\n".encode())
        gnuplot.write( "set term png size 1920,1010 \n".encode() )
        gnuplot.write( "set output \"acceleration.png\" \n".encode() )
        gnuplot.write( "set xlabel \"timesteps\" \n".encode() )
        gnuplot.write( "set ylabel \"acceleration\" \n".encode() )
        gnuplot.write( "plot " %filename " using 1 with lines lt -1 lw 0.5 title 'X axis' \n " .encode() )
        gnuplot.write( " " %filename " using 2 with lines lt 1 lw 0.5 title 'Y axis'  \n " .encode() )
        gnuplot.write( " " %filename " using 3 with lines lt 2 lw 0.5 title 'Z axis' \n " .encode() )
```

However filename is taken literally. I get the following error from gnuplot:

> line 0: warning: Skipping unreadable file "" %filename ""
>            line 0: No data in plot

I have already parsed filename from sys.argv and made sure it is correct and safe and now I need to tell gnuplot to plot whatever name the filename is set to.
I've tried using escape characters, removing the ambersand but I'm obviously using the wrong syntax.

Can someone please help ?

EDIT:

Thank's to agf I've solved the python formating issue:

```
gnuplot.write( "plot \"%s\" using 1 with lines lt -1 lw 0.5 title 'X axis' ,\ \n " %filename )
        gnuplot.write( "\"%s\" using 2 with lines lt 1 lw 0.5 title 'Y axis' ,\ \n " %filename )
        gnuplot.write( "\"%s\" using 3 with lines lt 2 lw 0.5 title 'Z axis' \n " %filename )
```

However now I have an issue with gnuplot. Normally when directly using gnuplot, i would type:

```
gnuplot> plot "state_log_6548032.data" using 4 with lines lt -1 lw 0.5 title "X axis" ,\
>"state_log_6548032.data" using 5 with lines lt 1 lw 0.5 title "Y axis" ,\
>"state_log_6548032.data" using 6 with lines lt 2 lw 0.5 title "Z axis"
```

However, sending these commands through python to gnuplot seems to cause errors:

```
gnuplot> plot "state_log_6548032.data" using 1 with lines lt -1 lw 0.5 title 'X axis' ,\ 
                                                                                       ^
         line 0: invalid character \

gnuplot> "state_log_6548032.data" using 2 with lines lt 1 lw 0.5 title 'Y axis' ,\ 
                                                                                 ^
         line 0: invalid character \

gnuplot> "state_log_6548032.data" using 3 with lines lt 2 lw 0.5 title 'Z axis' 
         ^
         line 0: invalid command
```

I'm betting it has to do with the ,\ and newline character ?

Comment: It's not still mantained, but try to have a look here: http://gnuplot-py.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want

```
    gnuplot.write("plot %s using 1 with lines lt -1 lw 0.5 title 'X axis' \n " % filename1)
```

See http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings for new style formatting and http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting for old style formatting, which looks like what you were trying to do.

Edit 2: I like part of wiso's suggestion too. Save the gnuplot commands in a file (with format codes for the variables you need to drop in), then just read that file in with Python and format it. This separates the gnuplot stuff and you don't need to worry about quoting or line endings.

If you want to send a lot of commands, I'd try writing putting all the strings in a list (preferably by reading them from a file with `file.readlines()`) then:

```
for line in lines:
    gnuplot.write(lines)
    gnuplot.flush()
```

So it gets sent the lines one at a time but you don't have to hard code a certain number.

Comment: You wouldn't also happen to know how to send to gnuplot many lines at once ? In gnuplot I usually send each data and it's parameter per line, ending with the ,\ but this doesn't seem to work here.

Comment: Try it with implicit string concatenation.

Comment: Thank you for the help, sadly this didn't help either. Problem is on the gnuplot side, not python.

Comment: How about looping over the lines, and flushing the buffer in between?

Comment: Will give it a try
Edit: Your solution is much cleaner, looping and placing the commands in a file, and I will have to do it because there are much more commands than the ones posted above.
However the error i keep getting seems to originate from the ",\" part. What I do not know is why I have to send ",\" in the console in the first place. Also in console i send ",\ ENTER" so I guessed it was in fact a ",\n" ? This seems to be causing my errors

Comment: I think when you do `\ ` (backlash-space) in Python, you're escaping the space, and I think when you do do `\ ` then hit enter in gnuplot you're escaping the newline. Did you try it with just `,\n` at the end? With just `,`? With just `\n`?

Answer (score 1):

As agf said the problem is how you format your string. Alternatively you can concatenate the string using `+` operator, even if formatting is usually better.

In general I think you should separate the gnuplot code to the python code.

In the gnuplot code `plot.gp` put how the data should be draw. Use your python script to generate the data and write them in a tabual format into a file, for example in a [temp file](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html). Then run your gnuplot script reading from the file, see for example [here](http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/datafile-e.html).

Comment: Or just have Python read the gnuplot instructions from a file and use string formatting to drop in variables. This separates things without having to write out the data and run the gnuplot script separately.

Comment: Thank you both for the advice, I will look into it. Sadly I was looking for a fast and dirty solution, but it seems this won't be so simple after all.